# TypeLoadException for 'OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait' when trying to run selenium test

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting the following error when trying to run my selenium webdriver tests from a user control I have created: 
An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in UserCreationFrontEnd.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not load type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait' from assembly 'WebDriver, Version=2.48.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Background story: I have created an app with some automated test suites in that allows people within my team without visual studio to run them. This app is a winforms app and is written in c# and uses user controls. I have added a user control into my selenium solution to run the selenium tests. When I run the user control from here the tests run as expected.

The issue appears when I add the user control into my main application and try and run the selenium tests from there.

The user control is displayed fine, but when I try to start the tests I get the error in my test start up (OneTimeSetUp).

Code:

```
        public void TestStartUp()
    {
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"O:\Testing\SDET\SeleniumWebDriver");
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        config = new MapsPageObjectModel.EnvironmentConfig(driver);
        navBar = new MapsPageObjectModel.NavigationBar(driver);
        homePage = new MapsPageObjectModel.Homepage(driver);
        createContact = new MapsPageObjectModel.CreateContact(driver);
        securityManager = new MapsPageObjectModel.SecurityManager(driver);
        companyPage = new MapsPageObjectModel.Company(driver);
        createEmployee = new MapsPageObjectModel.CreateEmployee(driver);
        roles = new MapsPageObjectModel.Roles(driver);
        UserCreationResults.Clear();
    }
```

The error happens on this line

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

Does anyone have any idea's?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Manage NuGet window and make sure you have installed same version of `Selenium.Support` and `Selenium.WebDriver` across all your projects in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have both usings in your .cs file:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
```

Also u need to have refences to WebDriver and WebDriver.Support.

Comment: I've got the usings and the references added into my project but I'm still getting the error.